# Belonging to Nullspace and Rowspace at the same time

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Prove that if the vector $v$ belongs both to the nullspace and the row space of a matrix $A$, then $v = 0$.

I did this solution but I don't know if it's right.

$V=A^Tb$ and $Av=0\Rightarrow AV=AA^Tv\Rightarrow A^2b=0\Rightarrow b=0 \Rightarrow v=0$

Comment: Usually, $AA^T \neq A^2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $A\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{x}^TA = \mathbf{v}^T$, then what is $\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v}$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $v$ is in Nul A, $<v,r> = 0$ for each row $r$ of A. So for any linear combination $w$ of the rows, $<w,v>=0$. But $v$, being in Row A, is itself such a linear combination $w$. So $<v,v>=0$.